# Formview with objectdatasource generating invalid update params

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I've a form view with various field in edit and an object datasource where I've defined my update parameters that my update method takes. I've set some of the fields in the edit template to read only because I want them to display.

Unfortunately they are getting passed in as update parameters somehow to my objectdatasource.
So, it is generating update parameters that causes my method to not match.

How can I exclude these parameters from getting sent to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

Change the Bind(field) syntax to Eval(field)

Anyone have other input feel free. If good I'll give you credit.